# Save Django ModelForm with CheckboxSelectMultiple with no boxes checked

Tags: django, django-forms

A Django Form using a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget posts back nothing for the field using the CheckboxSelectMultiple widget if no boxes are checked.

```
class AlarmForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Alarm
        fields = ['phone_contacts', 'disabled']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.instance.user
        self.fields["phone_contacts"].widget = forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['phone_contacts'].queryset = user.phonecontact_set
```

If the user viewing the form checks no checkboxes, the idea is that the model's `phonecontact_set` field ( a `ManyToManyField`) should be cleared.  Instead, if no boxes are check, that field isn't saved at all.  This is apparently because unchecked check boxes include no values in the form POST in the web browser.

Still, it seems there must be a way to make Django do this without completely re-implementing the save functionality, but I can't seem to find the Django way to do this..

Comment: can you also share the view for that form ?

Comment: does the `ManyToManyField` you refer to allow null fields?